# How can I get sender ID using Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a logger bot which will log everything said in a server. I need the sender ID to @mention the user who said something so that it can be traced to the original author. How can I get the user's ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the command author's id, you would want to do something like this:

```py
@bot.command(name="id")
async def _id(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send('Your ID is: ' + str(author.id))
```

you get the ID with .id
if you would like to get a mentioned users id, just add a .id to the end of a discord.Member variable.